# Plotly 5.6.0 Sunburst shows empty output

Tags: plotly, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to plot a sunburst chart with plotly 5.6.0 but the output I get is empty.
I use a simple dataframe with 5 category columns and one value column.
Also the following error is displayed:

> The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

I cannot upgrde to 5.8.0 because it is not yet available in my organisation.
Any other hints?

[image]

```
import plotly.express as px
px.sunburst(data_frame=data_ACT,
           values='Value',
           path=['Mode','Type'])
```

UPDATE

Filtering for values > 0 does not help either:

```
px.sunburst(data_frame=data_ACT[data_ACT['Value'] > 0],
           values='Value',
           path=['Mode','Type'])
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A common issue with starbursts in plotly is that if you have any negative values the plot will be empty. Make sure all your values are positive